# Image not showing on slow networks

Tags: android, push-notification

The thing is when i send a push notification, if the network strength is good the image will display on the mobile but when the network is slow there is no image but a blank white div is on android notification

I am using Google FCM.

Comment: Download the compressed image on slower networks.

Comment: the image is already compressed and less than 40kb and we are using s3 bucket as image distribution server

Comment: It typically takes 3 seconds to download 40 kb image on 2g network. You can try WebP format instead of PNG or JPEG. You can try compressing the image further if the image quality is not lost.

Comment: Otherwise, if the network speed is very less, you can start listening to network changes and decide whether to show the notification.